# Is there an Rx operator for combining the latest from streams 1 and 2 only when stream 2 emits things?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

Here's my attempt at drawing the marble diagram --

`STREAM 1 = A----B----C---------D------>
               (magical operator)
STREAM 2 = 1----------2-----3-----4--->
STREAM 3 = 1A---------2C----3C----4D-->`

I am basically looking for something that generates stream 3 from streams 1 and 2. Basically, whenever something is emitted from stream 2, it combines it with the latest from stream 1. `combineLatest` is similar to what I want but I only want things emitted from stream 3 when something is emitted from stream 2, not stream 1. Does an operator like this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`withLatestFrom` seems to fit exactly what I was looking for - http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom

Answer (score 5):

There is an operator that does what you need: One overload of `sample` takes another observable instead of duration as a parameter. The documentation is here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#sample-or-throttlelast

The usage (I'll give examples in scala):

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable
import scala.concurrent.duration
import duration._

def o = Observable.interval(100.milli)
def sampler = Observable.interval(180.milli)

// Often, you just need the sampled observable
o.sample(sampler).take(10).subscribe(x ⇒ println(x +  ", "))
Thread.sleep(2000)
// or, as for your use case
o.combineLatest(sampler).sample(sampler).take(10).subscribe(x ⇒ println(x +  ", "))
Thread.sleep(2000)
```

The output:

```
0, 
2, 
4, 
6, 
7, 
9, 
11, 
13, 
15, 
16, 

(2,0), 
(4,1), 
(6,2), 
(7,3), 
(9,4), 
(11,5), 
(13,6), 
(15,7), 
(16,8), 
(18,9),
```

There is a slight catch in that duplicate entries from the sampled observable are swallowed (see discussion at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/912). Other than that, I think it is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: For our use case, that "slight catch" makes this unusable.  We do this all the time for attaching UI to some state.  A UI element exposes an observable (we usually make it a boolean) that fires on a press, the state exposes an observable, we combine them, and the result is an observable of the state that only fires when the button is pressed.  Deduping either side of this won't work.  (Our code that does the equivalent of sample() without the dedup is in F#, so it's probably not helpful.)

Comment: Yeah, I know, I had to implement a dedup-free version of `sample` myself as well. I use it for exactly the same purpose as you. If you check the discussion, I've tried to convince the RxJava folks about the usefulness of the dedupped behavior (and the uselesness of the original behavior), but no luck. I'm now migrating to Monix (another Scala Rx lib, not because of this issue, though), and it has a `sampleRepeated` operator that does what I want, so, well, finally, yeah :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there isn't a single existing operator that will do what you want. However you can compose one by using `CombineLatest` and `DistinctUntilChanged` as follows:

```
var joined = Observable.CombineLatest(sourceA, sourceB, (a,b) => new { A = a, B = b })
  .DistinctUntilChanged(pair => pair.B);
```

EDIT:

The above will work as long as the values for STREAM 1 change each time. If they do not, then then use the following, which is less clear, but works in all situations (that I've tested anyway).

```
var joined = Observable.Join(
    sourceB,
    sourceA,
    _ => Observable.Return(Unit.Default),
    _ => sourceA,
    (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b });
```

The `Join` operator is never intuitive to me, the best explanation I've found is [here](http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html).

In answer to @Matthew's comment

```
var buttonClicks = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventArgs>(this,
    "MouseLeftButtonDown")
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default);

var sequence = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

var joined = Observable.Join(
  buttonClicks,
  sequence,
  _ => Observable.Return(Unit.Default),
  _ => sequence,
  (b, s) => s); // No info in button click here
```

Comment: I was going to write up an answer such as this, but note that this does lose some information... Since it's possible for `b` to fire twice with the same object, this may end up filtering out some events that should be sent through from B. To account for this, B would need to be time-stamped, and the `DistinctUntilChanged` would need to work off of that.

Comment: interesting, let's say stream B is generated from button clicks. how would i set that up so that every time a button is clicked, an increasing number is emitted so that I don't lose information?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris and @ Matthew, you raise good points, I'll get back to you.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris and @ Matthew, fixed now I think.

Comment: @MatthewFinlay Looks good. Apparently `Zip` has an overload which takes an `IEnumerable`, so *maybe* it would work by zipping `new [] { 0, 1 }.Repeat()`. Just a thought though. This works great, far as I can tell (ok unless the events occur simultaneously and the timestamps are the same, but what's the likelihood of that?).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fairly simple way to do it:

```
var query = stream2.Zip(
   stream1.MostRecent(' '),
   (s2,s1) => string.Format("{0}{1}", s2, s1));
```

`MostRecent` can be supplied a "zero" value which is used in the event stream1 has not emitted yet. This could be null for reference types, but I used a `char` for stream1 so supplied a space.

Comment: if stream 2 emitted a value but stream 2 didn't, would that trigger an event? I only care about events generated by stream 2 and just want to bring along whatever the current stream 1 value is.

Comment: It will only emit when stream2 emits.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `Switch` operator is the key here.

Try this:

```
var query =
    stream1
        .Select(s1 => stream2.Select(s2 => new { s1, s2 }))
        .Switch();
```

The following test code:

```
query
    .Select(s => String.Format("{0}{1}", s.s2, s.s1))
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

stream1.OnNext('A');
stream2.OnNext(1);
stream1.OnNext('B');
stream1.OnNext('C');
stream2.OnNext(2);
stream2.OnNext(3);
stream1.OnNext('D');
stream2.OnNext(4);
```

Gives these results:

```
1A
2C
3C
4D
```

Please let me know if this is correct.

Comment: Not clear if this is not correct from the requirements, but I suspect there's a problem if stream2 emits first. I have addressed this in my attempt!

Answer (score 0):

A solution

```
    public static IObservable<TR> Sample<TSource, TSampler, TR>
        (this IObservable<TSource> source,
         IObservable<TSampler> sampler,
         Func<TSource, TSampler, TR> combiner)
    {
        return source.Publish
           (rs => sampler
               .Zip
                 ( rs.MostRecent(default(TSource))
                 , (samplerElement, sourceElement)
                     => combiner(sourceElement, samplerElement)
                 )
               .SkipUntil(rs)
           );
    }
```

with a test case because this kind of thing is tricky to get right.

```
public class SampleSpec : ReactiveTest
{
    TestScheduler _Scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    [Fact]
    public void ShouldWork()
    {
        var sampler = _Scheduler.CreateColdObservable
            ( OnNext(10, "A")
            , OnNext(20, "B")
            , OnNext(30, "C")
            , OnNext(40, "D")
            , OnNext(50, "E")
            , OnNext(60, "F")
            );

        var source = _Scheduler.CreateColdObservable
            ( Enumerable
                .Range(5,100)
                .Where(i=>i%10!=0)
                .Select(i=>OnNext(i,i)).ToArray());

        var sampled = source.Sample
            (sampler, Tuple.Create);

        var actual = _Scheduler.Start
            (() =>
             sampled
             , created: 0
             , subscribed: 1
             , disposed: 1000);

        actual.Messages.Count()
              .Should()
              .Be(6);

        var messages = actual.Messages.Take(6)
                             .Select(v => v.Value.Value)
                             .ToList();

        messages[0].Should().Be(Tuple.Create(9,"A"));
        messages[1].Should().Be(Tuple.Create(19,"B"));
        messages[2].Should().Be(Tuple.Create(29, "C"));
        messages[3].Should().Be(Tuple.Create(39, "D"));
        messages[4].Should().Be(Tuple.Create(49, "E"));
        messages[5].Should().Be(Tuple.Create(59, "F"));

    }
}
```